# Laravel Referencing Foreign Key Data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5

Noob question incoming..

> $data = DB::table('fquotes')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

I have this query which is pulling all data from fquotes. Each item has a cid which is linked to a customer id in another table. How do I include a column (name) from the customers table matching each row pulled?

I want to display the data:

customer name from customers row - fquotes row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call `get()` which will execute the query, call the `join()` method and it will join your table on the other table by the specified column.

```
$data = DB::table('fquotes')
    ->select('customers.id as customer_id', 'fquotes.id as fquotes_id', DB::raw('*'))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->join('customers', 'fquotes.cid', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! It's often the most basic PHP stuff that everyone should know that is hard to find an answer on, because it's so simple.. :)

Comment: I'm getting another issue with this. The ID from customers is overriding the ID from fquotes in the returned object. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you can alias them in the select, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use without joining, just use a foreach

```
  public function index(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $items = ReportGlAssignment::where('shop_id', $id)->paginate(10);

        foreach ($items as $item ){
          $bill =  BillingAssignment::where('id',$item->billing_assignment_id )->pluck('assignment');
          $item['billing_assignment_id'] = $bill;
        }

        return response()->json($items);
    }
```

It will show the name of your foreign key data,

```
{
id: 7,
designation: "​Food Service",
income_gl: "333",
expense_gl: "333",
billing_assignment_id: "bgjjnhkj",
shop_id: 12,
created_at: "2017-08-21 07:26:48",
updated_at: "2017-08-23 09:35:54"
},
```